# How do I get FubuMVC to work on WinXP with IIS 5.1?

Tags: iis, iis-5, windows-xp, fubumvc

How do I get FubuMVC to work on WinXP with IIS 5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to.  I think it works with IIS 6, but older versions may not have the ability to route requests like the framework requires (but that's a guess).

Answer (score 0):

FubuMVC docs at http://mvc.fubu-project.org/documentation indicate that:

*FubuMVC can work with IIS 6 (Windows 2003) and IIS 6.1 (XP), but it’s more complicated to set up. This guide will focus on IIS 7.*

(I suspect that IIS 6.1 on XP is a typo of IIS 5.1)

Does anyone have any alternative information - either an explicit "can't work" or a "this is how I bodged it?"